# Is there anyway to mutate values in the svelte store as the client?

Tags: javascript, web, svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently building a site using Svelte.
A thought crossed my mind in a security perspective.
Is there anyway to mutate the values of the Svelte store as the client?
If so how and with what tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is irrelevant what happens with Svelte stores, because *none* of the code on the client can be trusted. Everything the server gets has to be validated, regardless of where it comes from.